# Wearing chakra specific color clothes?

Tags: spirituality, sadhana, chakras

We know that each chakra has a specific color associated with it and that there are certain types of food or gems specified in our texts for each chakra that helps balancing/activating/aligning that particular chakra but my question is does wearing chakra specific colored clothes have any impact on the chakras? Does it in any way help in balancing the chakra?

Answers with references from scriptures or renowned gurus would be preferred.